# How do I check if table exists and it's not empty in one IF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've tried to do this:

```
if OBJECT_ID('a_b_Stage2_supA_demB') is not null
and (select COUNT(*) from a_b_Stage2_supA_demB) > 0
```

But SQL Server returns an error when `a_b_Stage2_supA_demB` does not exist, because it still tries to check second condition even though first side of "and" condition is already failed.

Thanks for help!

Comment: On what basis are you saying that the 2nd condition is checked even though the 1st one has failed ?

Comment: Because sql returns error when trying to perform
select COUNT(*) from a_b_Stage2_supA_demB
in non existing table-1st condition has failed but 2nd condition 
is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible.  SQL Server will check to ensure that all object references (within the base code path) exist before compiling.  How about no if statements?

```
begin try
    exec('declare @x int = (
              select 1 / COUNT(*)
              from a_b_Stage2_supA_demB)');
    print 'true';
end try
begin catch
    print 'false';
end catch
```

Comment: That is always the ultimate goal, isn't it?  Glad I could help!

Comment: You shouldn't force an exception to do this.  It can be done in a number of ways without using Try Catch to alter the flow of the program.

Answer (score 3):

DMV's can easily solve your problem:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from sys.tables t 
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions p on t.object_id = p.object_id 
    WHERE t.name = 'a_b_Stage2_supA_demB' and p.rows > 0)
.....
```

Comment: this is perfect and I don't know why it's not the accepted answer... thanks! (if you're still around)

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('a_b_Stage2_supA_demB') is not null
    IF select COUNT(*) from a_b_Stage2_supA_demB > 0
        .....
```

Comment: The problem is, that I need them to do the same thing when each one is "false":
If object_id is null do a,b,c,d...
If object_id not null but count(*)=0 do a,b,c,d....

Comment: While this works, @MichaelCherevko will have to implement the false condition twice.  Also, probably better to use `if exists(select * from table)`

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dept') is not NULL
BEGIN
IF exists(SELECT 1 FROM dept)
PRINT 'exists with rows'
END
```

Comment: Same problem that in first answer.